# How to extract table from NHC website in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here,

```
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/
```

There is a table under the "Data & Products" section. I want to extract the table and save it to a CSV file. I wrote this basic code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I only know the basics of **scraping**. Please, guide me from here. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to extract the table itself or the data that is linked by the table?

Comment: I want to extract the data inside the table. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: Okay, so you want to download the zip and other data types and create a table out of it?

Comment: Yes, I want to download the zip and other files inside the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know but i guess that this is what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.get('href'):
        if '.' in a.get('href').split('/')[-1]\
                and 'html' not in a.get('href')\
                and '.php' not in a.get('href')\
                and 'http' not in a.get('href')\
                and 'mailto' not in a.get('href'):
            print('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov' + a.get('href'))
```

prints:

```
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/al112017_5day_020.zip
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_CONE.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_TRACK.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_WW.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.govforecast/archive/al092020_5day_latest.zip
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_CONE_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_TRACK_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_WW_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.govforecast/archive/al102020_5day_latest.zip
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL102020_CONE_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL102020_TRACK_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL102020_WW_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/al112017_fcst_020.zip
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_initialradii_020adv.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_forecastradii_020adv.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.govforecast/archive/al092020_fcst_latest.zip
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_initialradii_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_forecastradii_latest.kmz
https://www.nhc.noaa.govforecast/archive/al102020_fcst_latest.zip
```

.. and so on...

Comment: I want the output in the form of a table as answered by @dimay. But, that table is missing is links. It has only texts. Is there any way to make links inside the table work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

# create csv file
df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @dimay. My goal is to extract the data inside the table like zip, kmz, shp files, and other links. Please, guide me on this.

Comment: if you want save table https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html